# Dividing values in the row by the closest maximum

Tags: r

I am trying to divide all of the values in the row by the closest maximum (if there is no 0 between the maximum and the value). What does exactly it mean I will show you on an example:

The original data:

```
Name     1st   2nd   3rd   4th   5th  6th  7th   
Gregg     0    30    50    10    0    30    60   
Mike     20    50    30    0     0    2      0
Susane   30    0     10    0    100   30     0   
Marcel    0    40    30    10    0    2      0
```

The script I write so far is able to find a local maximas in such data. It ignores the maximas if the value is not atleast 20% of the highest maximum in the row.

That's an output:

```
Name     1st   2nd   3rd   4th   5th  6th  7th   
Gregg     0    0      1    0     0    0     1   
Mike      0    1      0    0     0    0     0
Susane    1    0      0    0     1    0     0  
Marcel    0    1      0    0     0    0     0
```

And now I will show you what exactly I want to achieve:

```
Name     1st   2nd   3rd   4th   5th  6th  7th   
Gregg     0    0.6   1     0.2   0    0.5    1   ## There are 2 local maximas (3rd & 7th), so firstly I divided a value in the 2nd by the local maximum in 3rd, than I divided 4th value by the maximum in 3th. In next (5th) is 0 so I value in 6th belongs to the next local maximum in position 7th.
Mike     0.4    1    0.6   0     0    0      0   ## Local maximum in 2nd position. Values in 1st and 3rd position divided by the maximum in 2nd. 
Susane    1     0    0     0     1    0.3    0   ## Local maximum in 1st, no other values close to this maximum. Another maximum in 5th so 6th divided by the maximum
Marcel    0     1    0.75  0.25  0    0      0   ## and so on...
```

I forgot to put my data and the script I use. Sorry I was in hurry.

My data:

```
> dput(head(tbl_all2))
structure(list(`Gene name` = structure(1:6, .Label = c("a2p1u8", 
"a2qab2", "a6zl23", "a6zlf3", "a6zq61", "a6ztx1", "a6zw47", "a6zya9", 
"a7a095", "a7a0l4", "b2g4d8", "b2g4i6", "b2g4p9", "b2g4u5", "b2zbw7", 
"b3lgx6", "b3lh69", "b3lha4", "b3ljq6", "b3llk0", "b3lp17", "b3ltm6", 
"b5vdr5", "b5ve00", "b5ve47", "b5ve66", "b5ve75", "b5vea8", "b5ved3", 
"b5vej5", "b5vfh0", "b5vfm0", "b5vfq6", "b5vg00", "b5vgm8", "b5vgw4", 
"b5vh77", "b5vi95", "b5vif4", "b5vik7", "b5vik8", "b5viu6", "b5vj32", 
"b5vjc2", "b5vji2", "b5vk65", "b5vkc9", "b5vkd1", "b5vkr2", "b5vkr3", 
"b5vl55", "b5vl71", "b5vla9", "b5vlc1", "b5vln1", "b5vlr4", "b5vm13", 
"b5vm96", "b5vmw7", "b5vn73", "b5vnb6", "b5vnc3", "b5vnj1", "b5vnk1", 
"b5vp33", "b5vp56", "b5vpx6", "b5vq26", "b5vq44", "b5vq52", "b5vqk3", 
"b5vrj3", "b5vrz5", "b5vs89", "b5vsy8", "c7gni0", "c7gq32", "c7gqn5", 
"c7gtn6", "c7gu46", "c7gwe7", "c7gxt0", "c8z669", "c8z6f5", "c8z6r4", 
"c8z6v4", "c8zbm1", "c8zcu8", "c8zd16", "c8zhg0", "e7k9a7", "e7k9i7", 
"e7ka19", "e7ka28", "e7kag3", "e7kak7", "e7kau5", "e7kb37", "e7kbg6", 
"e7kbp6", "e7kde5", "e7kdf5", "e7kdl8", "e7kec6", "e7kek6", "e7ker2", 
"e7kez8", "e7kfj1", "e7kg86", "e7kgg6", "e7kgj9", "e7kgm9", "e7kh79", 
"e7khz2", "e7kid1", "e7kid2", "e7kij3", "e7kip9", "e7kiv1", "e7kj59", 
"e7kjc9", "e7kjz8", "e7kkg8", "e7kks4", "e7kkx7", "e7klq2", "e7km62", 
"e7kmw1", "e7kni6", "e7knq6", "e7knx6", "e7kp09", "e7kps9", "e7kql6", 
"e7kqt5", "e7kr71", "e7krc8", "e7krj9", "e7krs0", "e7ks72", "e7ksf4", 
"e7ksg0", "e7ksv0", "e7ku26", "e7kui4", "e7kuz1", "e7kv21", "e7kvp5", 
"e7lr73", "e7lrn1", "e7ls46", "e7ls63", "e7lsa7", "e7lsk8", "e7lsm3", 
"e7lsy6", "e7lte7", "e7ltk1", "e7ltv7", "e7lu34", "e7lun6", "e7lup5", 
"e7lux5", "e7lv27", "e7lw21", "e7lw44", "e7lwa5", "e7lwl6", "e7lwm3", 
"e7lx88", "e7lxj7", "e7lxn8", "e7lxp5", "e7ly02", "e7lyz3", "e7lz85", 
"e7lzh7", "e7lzn6", "e7m129", "e7ney3", "e7nf47", "e7nfe5", "e7nfq5", 
"e7nfz0", "e7ng34", "e7nh47", "e7nh77", "e7nhb2", "e7nhq7", "e7nie7", 
"e7nii6", "e7nir5", "e7nje2", "e7njk4", "e7njv1", "e7nk19", "e7nk28", 
"e7nkm6", "e7nl37", "e7nl74", "e7nlc7", "e7nlm1", "e7nlr2", "e7nlt8", 
"e7nm31", "e7nm99", "e7nmz4", "e7nn89", "e7npc6", "e7q121", "e7q1a1", 
"e7q1e1", "e7q1k7", "e7q1t1", "e7q1x8", "e7q2c3", "e7q2x6", "e7q3f3", 
"e7q3m4", "e7q3x2", "e7q4c4", "e7q4i8", "e7q5g3", "e7q5l9", "e7q5p8", 
"e7q6a9", "e7q6d5", "e7q800", "e7q814", "e7q825", "e7q833", "e7q8i6", 
"e7q8q5", "e7q8r1", "e7q8u9", "e7q8y1", "e7qbg0", "e7qcc5", "e7qcf3", 
"e7qd66", "e7qdy4", "e7qdy8", "e7qe39", "e7qf79", "e7qfn0", "e7qgb5", 
"e7qh38", "e7qh57", "e7qh90", "e7qhj0", "e7qhj7", "e7qhk8", "e7qi53", 
"e7qi89", "e7qii2", "e7qiq0", "e7qiv9", "e7qje4", "e7qjm1", "e7qjn3", 
"e7qjz3", "e7qka0", "e7qkh1", "e7qki3", "e7ql07", "e7ql23", "e7ql56", 
"e7qle4", "e7qlh7", "e7qlm1", "e7qlq3", "e9p8k6", "e9p9c8", "e9p9h6", 
"e9p9y2", "f8ka88", "g1uaw4", "g2w8j6", "g2wax6", "g2wbs0", "g2wbt1", 
"g2wc37", "g2we94", "g2weh9", "g2wej8", "g2wf31", "g2wgt2", "g2whe0", 
"g2wi84", "g2wlm2", "g2wmh7", "g2wmk0", "g2wnc9", "h0gc43", "h0gc45", 
"h0gc46", "h0gc71", "h0gcc4", "h0gce3", "h0gce7", "h0gcg9", "h0gcx2", 
"h0gd06", "h0gd44", "h0gd98", "h0gda5", "h0gda8", "h0gdj5", "h0gdq8", 
"h0gdr5", "h0gdt8", "h0ger5", "h0geu6", "h0gf09", "h0gf24", "h0gf63", 
"h0gfb9", "h0gfx9", "h0gg75", "h0ggk6", "h0ggy4", "h0gh33", "h0gh37", 
"h0ghf6", "h0ghg0", "h0ghh6", "h0ghk6", "h0gig2", "h0gim1", "h0giq8", 
"h0gir4", "h0gj73", "h0gk02", "h0gk39", "h0gk56", "h0gkc0", "h0gkh0", 
"h0gl26", "h0gl41", "h0gle1", "h0glz7", "h0gm98", "h0gmi5", "h0gmp1", 
"h0gmp4", "h0gms2", "h0gmz5", "h0gn89", "h0gp57", "h0gp81", "h0gp99", 
"h0gpm9", "h0gq90", "h0gqv1", "h0gqv6", "h0gr16", "h0gr46", "h0gr62", 
"h0grh5", "h0grj7", "h0grp5", "h0gru2", "h0gry2", "h0grz3", "h0gs82", 
"h0gs88", "h0gsa9", "h0gsk0", "h0gsl8", "h0gsu6", "h0gtf9", "h0gti8", 
"h0gtn2", "h0gts6", "h0gu87", "h0gug5", "h0guj4", "h0gur2", "h0gut3", 
"h0guu5", "h0gux5", "h0gv21", "h0gv78", "h0gvm9", "h0gvn0", "h0gw05", 
"h0gw07", "h0gwi0", "h0gwr8", "h0gx56", "h0gx58", "h0gx70", "h0gx75", 
"h0gxf9", "h0gxg6", "h0gxy4", "h0gxz9", "h0gy93", "h0gys0", "h0gyu8", 
"h0gyz2", "h0gz20", "h0gzc0", "h0gzd5", "h0gzx8", "h0h061", "h0h0j5", 
"h0h0s1", "h0h0t9", "h0h1f1", "h0h1m4", "h0h1r9", "h0h1t7", "h0h216", 
"h0h220", "h0h251", "h0h294", "h0h2j1", "i7ji35", "i7ktc2", "n1nwq1", 
"n1nxi5", "n1ny73", "n1nyf2", "n1nyt5", "n1nyw8", "n1nz14", "n1nzs8", 
"n1p080", "n1p0a4", "n1p0i3", "n1p0w1", "n1p1a9", "n1p1r0", "n1p242", 
"n1p2s1", "n1p2s2", "n1p3w6", "n1p4p6", "n1p4q6", "n1p4r9", "n1p548", 
"n1p5a6", "n1p5i1", "n1p605", "n1p7b3", "n1p858", "n1p8d9", "n1p8f8", 
"n1p8l5", "n1p910", "n1pa29", "n1pa30", "o13429", "o13516", "o14455", 
"o14467", "o43137", "p00358", "p00359", "p00360", "p00431", "p00445", 
"p00498", "p00549", "p00560", "p00635", "p00729", "p00812", "p00815", 
"p00817", "p00830", "p00890", "p00899", "p00924", "p00925", "p00931", 
"p00942", "p00950", "p00958", "p01120", "p01123", "p02309", "p02400", 
"p02406", "p02557", "p02829", "p02992", "p02994", "p03962", "p03965", 
"p04037", "p04046", "p04050", "p04076", "p04147", "p04161", "p04456", 
"p04801", "p04802", "p04806", "p04807", "p05150", "p05317", "p05318", 
"p05319", "p05373", "p05694", "p05737", "p05738", "p05739", "p05740", 
"p05743", "p05744", "p05745", "p05747", "p05749", "p05750", "p05755", 
"p05756", "p05759", "p06101", "p06106", "p06168", "p06169", "p06174", 
"p06208", "p06244", "p06367", "p06634", "p06738", "p07149", "p07170", 
"p07172", "p07244", "p07245", "p07246", "p07256", "p07257", "p07258", 
"p07259", "p07260", "p07262", "p07263.2", "p07264", "p07274", 
"p07275", "p07277", "p07281", "p07283", "p07284", "p07285", "p07560", 
"p07702", "p07703", "p07806.2", "p07884.2", "p07991", "p08465", 
"p08518", "p08524", "p08536", "p08566", "p09064", "p09436", "p09624", 
"p09733", "p09734", "p09880", "p09938", "p0c2h7", "p0c2h8", "p0cs90", 
"p0ct05", "p0cx11", "p0cx24", "p0cx26", "p0cx30", "p0cx32", "p0cx34", 
"p0cx36", "p0cx38", "p0cx40", "p0cx42", "p0cx44", "p0cx48", "p0cx50", 
"p0cx52", "p0cx54", "p0cx56", "p0cx83", "p0cx85", "p10081", "p10127", 
"p10356", "p10591", "p10592", "p10594.2", "p10659", "p10664", 
"p10869", "p10964", "p11076", "p11154", "p11353", "p11412", "p11484", 
"p11745", "p12612", "p12630", "p12709", "p12904", "p12945", "p13188", 
"p13298", "p13663", "p14065", "p14120", "p14126", "p14127", "p14306", 
"p14540", "p14743", "p14832", "p14843", "p14904", "p15019", "p15108", 
"p15180", "p15202", "p15303", "p15424", "p15454", "p15496", "p15624", 
"p15625", "p15646", "p15703", "p15705", "p15790", "p15873", "p15992", 
"p16120", "p16140", "p16370", "p16387", "p16467", "p16474", "p16550", 
"p16603", "p16649", "p16861", "p17076", "p17255", "p17423", "p17505", 
"p17555", "p17649", "p17709", "p17967", "p18544", "p18562", "p18962", 
"p19097", "p19262", "p19414", "p19454", "p19812", "p19881", "p19882", 
"p20081", "p20133", "p20433", "p20434", "p20436", "p20459", "p20967", 
"p21242", "p21243", "p21524", "p21801", "p21826", "p22023", "p22108", 
"p22138", "p22141", "p22146", "p22202", "p22203", "p22217", "p22336", 
"p22515", "p22696", "p22803", "p23180", "p23248", "p23254", "p23301", 
"p23638", "p23639", "p23724", "p23776", "p24000", "p24280", "p24521", 
"p24783", "p24859", "p25036", "p25043", "p25293", "p25328", "p25332", 
"p25359", "p25373", "p25375", "p25443", "p25451", "p25491", "p25567", 
"p25572", "p25631", "p25632", "p25638", "p25654", "p25694", "p25719", 
"p26321", "p26637", "p26755", "p26783", "p26784", "p26785", "p26786", 
"p27466", "p27472", "p27476", "p27614", "p27616", "p27929", "p28000", 
"p28241", "p28272", "p28273", "p28274", "p28319", "p28495", "p28707", 
"p28777", "p28834", "p29311", "p29453", "p29509", "p29547", "p29952", 
"p30402", "p30656", "p30657", "p30952", "p31115", "p31116", "p31209", 
"p31373", "p31383", "p31412", "p31539", "p31688", "p32178", "p32179", 
"p32288", "p32324", "p32327", "p32337", "p32347", "p32356", "p32377", 
"p32379", "p32381", "p32445", "p32452", "p32459", "p32460", "p32461", 
"p32469", "p32471", "p32474", "p32481", "p32485", "p32486", "p32495", 
"p32497", "p32527", "p32529", "p32558", "p32565", "p32582", "p32589", 
"p32590", "p32598", "p32604", "p32614", "p32626", "p32628", "p32643", 
"p32656", "p32767", "p32771", "p32774", "p32775", "p32835", "p32836", 
"p32860", "p32895", "p32905", "p32939", "p33201", "p33204", "p33298", 
"p33307", "p33312", "p33315", "p33317", "p33327", "p33330", "p33399", 
"p33401", "p33412", "p33416", "p33442", "p33734", "p34162", "p34167", 
"p34223", "p34227", "p34760", "p35176", "p35184", "p35189", "p35195", 
"p35691", "p35719", "p35844", "p36008", "p36010", "p36015", "p36017", 
"p36018", "p36037", "p36047", "p36060", "p36069", "p36104", "p36136", 
"p36156", "p36159", "p36421", "p37012", "p37254", "p37291", "p37292", 
"p37302", "p37303", "p37898", "p38009", "p38011", "p38013", "p38061", 
"p38066", "p38067", "p38071", "p38075", "p38081", "p38088.2", 
"p38109", "p38113", "p38115", "p38145", "p38197", "p38199", "p38203", 
"p38205", "p38237", "p38254", "p38260", "p38328", "p38331", "p38431", 
"p38439", "p38523", "p38555", "p38616", "p38620", "p38623", "p38625", 
"p38627", "p38628", "p38687", "p38688", "p38693", "p38697", "p38698", 
"p38701", "p38707", "p38710", "p38711", "p38715", "p38716", "p38754", 
"p38764", "p38765", "p38774", "p38777", "p38787", "p38788", "p38791", 
"p38792", "p38797", "p38804", "p38820", "p38840", "p38841", "p38858", 
"p38861", "p38879", "p38882", "p38888", "p38891", "p38902", "p38930", 
"p38972", "p38986", "p38999", "p39076", "p39079", "p39522", "p39676", 
"p39683", "p39692", "p39708", "p39714", "p39721", "p39929", "p39939", 
"p39954", "p39958", "p39976", "p39979", "p39988", "p39990", "p40011", 
"p40016", "p40029", "p40032", "p40037", "p40043", "p40047", "p40054", 
"p40069", "p40070", "p40075", "p40087", "p40089", "p40106", "p40185", 
"p40302", "p40354", "p40363", "p40414", "p40422", "p40454", "p40459", 
"p40495", "p40498", "p40506", "p40509", "p40510", "p40531", "p40545", 
"p40553", "p40581", "p40586", "p40825.2", "p41057", "p41058", 
"p41277", "p41338", "p41752", "p41805", "p41811", "p41816", "p41835", 
"p41895", "p41896", "p41920", "p41921", "p41939", "p41940", "p42935", 
"p42936", "p42941", "p42943", "p43561", "p43567", "p43583", "p43590", 
"p43593", "p43616", "p43621", "p46151", "p46654", "p46655", "p46669", 
"p46672", "p46680", "p46948", "p46959", "p46969", "p46990", "p47008", 
"p47079", "p47089", "p47095", "p47096", "p47103", "p47117", "p47119", 
"p47120", "p47164", "p47173", "p47176", "p47771", "p48164", "p48362", 
"p48363", "p48445", "p48526", "p48567", "p48589", "p49017", "p49089", 
"p49090", "p49166", "p49167", "p49367", "p49435", "p49723", "p49775", 
"p49954", "p49957", "p50086", "p50094", "p50095", "p50101", "p50264", 
"p50861", "p50946", "p51401", "p51601", "p51996", "p52488", "p52489", 
"p52910", "p52918", "p53072", "p53090", "p53095", "p53110", "p53111", 
"p53128", "p53144", "p53164", "p53177", "p53183", "p53184", "p53196", 
"p53221", "p53228", "p53235", "p53255", "p53256", "p53265", "p53270", 
"p53303", "p53315", "p53319", "p53334", "p53342", "p53598", "p53615", 
"p53633", "p53720", "p53727", "p53731", "p53759", "p53834", "p53839", 
"p53848", "p53909", "p53912", "p53920", "p53980", "p53981", "p54113", 
"p54114", "p54115", "p54838", "p54839", "p54885", "p60010", "p80210", 
"p83774", "p87262", "p89886", "q00055", "q00618", "q00711", "q00764", 
"q00955", "q01855", "q02326", "q02455", "q02642", "q02648", "q02725", 
"q02821", "q02892", "q02933", "q03034", "q03048", "q03102", "q03161", 
"q03262", "q03280", "q03532", "q03558", "q03629", "q03677", "q03690", 
"q03771", "q03774", "q03940", "q04066", "q04119", "q04120", "q04175", 
"q04178", "q04212", "q04225", "q04336", "q04401", "q04409", "q04430", 
"q04432", "q04491", "q04533", "q04636", "q04660", "q04728", "q04792", 
"q04894", "q04947", "q04951", "q05016", "q05022", "q05506", "q05515", 
"q05533", "q05583", "q05636", "q05778", "q05788", "q05905", "q05911", 
"q05933", "q05946", "q05979", "q06053", "q06103", "q06137", "q06146", 
"q06151", "q06252", "q06338", "q06385", "q06406", "q06408", "q06440", 
"q06494", "q06523", "q06608", "q06624", "q06625", "q06672", "q06706", 
"q07381", "q07505", "q07527", "q07532", "q07551", "q07589", "q07648", 
"q07938", "q08162", "q08220", "q08245", "q08421", "q08634", "q08647", 
"q08686", "q08745", "q08920", "q08924", "q08952", "q08971", "q08977", 
"q08985", "q12008", "q12009", "q12040", "q12074", "q12091", "q12109", 
"q12118", "q12122", "q12123", "q12159", "q12168", "q12189", "q12211", 
"q12242", "q12277", "q12283", "q12306", "q12314", "q12329", "q12335", 
"q12341", "q12363", "q12377", "q12400", "q12408", "q12414", "q12434", 
"q12447", "q12449", "q12455", "q12458", "q12460", "q12464", "q12496", 
"q12522", "q12525", "q12680", "q3e754", "q3e792", "q3e7x9", "q3e7y3", 
"q6fjy0_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fl72_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fmr2_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fns7_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fph8_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fpi1_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fpn8_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fpp1_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fr31_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6frs2_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fst2_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6ftb3_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6ftj1_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6ftk5_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fvr0_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fwr8_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fx34_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fxu9_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6q560", "q74z16", "q74z48", "q74zf6", "q74zm9", "q750e3", "q750u5", 
"q750z7", "q751d8", "q752q7", "q752w6", "q753p8", "q753t3", "q753w1", 
"q753y2", "q754c8", "q754d6", "q754f6", "q755g1", "q755g8", "q755q5", 
"q756e2", "q756e7", "q756f7", "q756k2", "q756u4", "q756y3", "q757i1", 
"q757l4", "q757n1", "q757y2", "q758l1", "q758t1", "q759a3", "q759a4", 
"q759a9", "q759i7", "q759v7", "q75aa5", "q75bc3", "q75bq6", "q75bv8", 
"q75c57", "q75cf8", "q75cn6", "q75df8", "q75dp6", "q75dq0", "q75ds7", 
"q75du3", "q75dw1", "q75en0", "q75ew2", "q75f01", "q87026", "q8j1f8", 
"q8j2m3", "q8mx29", "q96vh4", "q99210", "q99258", "q99312", "q9p4c2", 
"s4vpl7", "s5s176", "t2a536", "v5rd14"), class = "factor"), `2_1` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.933959669839227, 0), `2_2` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 14.2445924025971, 
0), `2_3` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1.84391659829476, 0), `2_4` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2_5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.850344700878792, 0), 
    `2_6` = c(0.0631240804031774, 0, 0, 1.11684072808048, 1, 
    1.29478435854497), `2_7` = c(0.135377134405041, 0, 0, 0.941579635959761, 
    0.389199799282971, 0.705215641455033), `2_8` = c(0.340634833543641, 
    0, 0, 1, 0.467857655108082, 0), `2_9` = c(1.43325438281299, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.157821181013907, 0), `2_10` = c(1.71425095521776, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.382740802185421, 0), `2_11` = c(0.715532320539672, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_12` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_13` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_14` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_15` = c(1.72759758284943, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_16` = c(1.71289858010354, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), `2_17` = c(0.747888289194788, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_18` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_19` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_20` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_21` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_22` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_23` = c(0, 0, 1.29452015085474, 0, 0, 
    0), `2_24` = c(0, 0, 0.852739924572629, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Gene name", 
"2_1", "2_2", "2_3", "2_4", "2_5", "2_6", "2_7", "2_8", "2_9", 
"2_10", "2_11", "2_12", "2_13", "2_14", "2_15", "2_16", "2_17", 
"2_18", "2_19", "2_20", "2_21", "2_22", "2_23", "2_24"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Script I use to get local maximas:

```
## Preparing a function ##
example <- c(5,2,3,2,1, 1, 2, 3)

localmaxima <- function(example) {
  x <- c(ifelse(diff(head(example, 2)) < 0, 1, NA), which(diff(sign(diff(example))) == -2) + 1, ifelse(diff(tail(example, 2)) > 0, length(example),  
                                                                                             NA))
  x <- as.vector(x[!is.na(x)])
  x <- x[example[x] >= 0.2 * max(example)]
}


## Creating a list - one element for each row - containing indices
## of local maximas including edges
indices <- apply(as.matrix(tbl_all2[, -1]), 1, FUN = localmaxima)


## Converting them to coordinates of matrix

coords <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(indices), FUN = function(i) (expand.grid(i, indices[[i]]))))


## Creating an empty matrix
empty <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(tbl_all2), ncol = ncol(tbl_all2) - 1)


## Setting the 1 at locations of local maximas
empty[as.matrix(coords)] <- 1


## Creating results by cbinding back the gene name and adding names to columns.
tbl_peak <- cbind(tbl_all2[, 1], as.data.frame(empty))
names(tbl_peak) <- names(tbl_all2)
```

Do you think it is possible to write such code ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, how you treat local maximum. I see some ambiguity in your example. I would treat 2 in second row 6th position equally as 30 in third row first position and 10 in same row 3rd position as well as 2 in fourth row 6th position. They all are local, that is separated by zeros. Your rule of ignoring the maximas if the value is not at least 20% of the highest maximum in the row, is it strict or arbitrary?

Comment: That's rule is strict. The local maximum has to be atleast 20% of the highest value in the row. That's why some of the local maximas are missing. I am trying to find the shape of the "peaks" by divinding values close to the local maximum by this local maximum. It's hard specify whose of the values in the row belong to one or other local maximum. That's why I started a bounty. If someone has any idea he can completely rewrite this script.

Comment: I'm personally curious to the context; what do you need it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localmaxima <- function(dat)
{
  dat_orig <- dat
  dat1 <- dat
  dat[,-1] <- 0
  n <- ncol(dat)

  #Spread maximum across columns until all hit zeroes
  while (!all(dat1 == dat))
  {
    dat <- dat1
    dat1[,2] <- ifelse(dat[,2]==0, 0, pmax( dat[,2],dat[,3]))
    dat1[,n] <- ifelse(dat[,n]==0, 0, pmax( dat[,n],dat[,n-1]))
    for (i in 3:(n-1)) dat1[,i] <- ifelse(dat[,i]==0, 0, pmax( dat[,i-1],dat[,i],dat[,i+1]))
  }

  #Exclude using 20% rule
  for (i in 1:nrow(dat1))
    dat1[i,-1] <- ifelse(dat1[i,-1]/max(dat1[i,-1]) <0.8, 0, dat1[i,-1])

  #Divide by maximum
  for (i in 1:nrow(dat1))
    dat[i,-1] <- ifelse(dat1[i,-1]==0, 0, dat_orig[i,-1]/dat1[i,-1])
  dat
}
```

Example 1
(note that Susane first differs from your answer - I've set it to zero at less than 80% of row maximum)

```
dat2
#    Name 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th
#1  Gregg   0  30  50  10   0  30  60
#2   Mike  20  50  30   0   0   2   0
#3 Susane  30   0  10   0 100  30   0
#4 Marcel   0  40  30  10   0   2   0

localmaxima(dat2)
#    Name 1st 2nd  3rd  4th 5th 6th 7th
#1  Gregg 0.0 0.6 1.00 0.20   0 0.5   1
#2   Mike 0.4 1.0 0.60 0.00   0 0.0   0
#3 Susane 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00   1 0.3   0
#4 Marcel 0.0 1.0 0.75 0.25   0 0.0   0
```

Example 2

```
   dat
    #  Gene name       2_1      2_2      2_3 2_4       2_5        2_6       2_7       2_8       2_9      2_10      2_11 2_12 2_13 2_14     2_15     2_16      2_17 2_18 2_19 2_20 2_21 2_22    2_23      2_24
    #1    a2p1u8 0.0000000  0.00000 0.000000   0 0.0000000 0.06312408 0.1353771 0.3406348 1.4332544 1.7142510 0.7155323    0    0    0 1.727598 1.712899 0.7478883    0    0    0    0    0 0.00000 0.0000000
    #2    a2qab2 0.0000000  0.00000 0.000000   0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0 0.000000 0.000000 1.0000000    0    0    0    0    0 0.00000 0.0000000
    #3    a6zl23 0.0000000  0.00000 0.000000   0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0    0 1.29452 0.8527399
    #4    a6zlf3 0.0000000  0.00000 0.000000   0 0.0000000 1.11684073 0.9415796 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0    0 0.00000 0.0000000
    #5    a6zq61 0.9339597 14.24459 1.843917   1 0.8503447 1.00000000 0.3891998 0.4678577 0.1578212 0.3827408 0.0000000    0    0    0 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0    0 0.00000 0.0000000
    #6    a6ztx1 0.0000000  0.00000 0.000000   0 0.0000000 1.29478436 0.7052156 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0    0 0.00000 0.0000000

    localmaxima(dat)
    #  Gene name        2_1 2_2       2_3        2_4        2_5        2_6        2_7        2_8        2_9      2_10      2_11 2_12 2_13 2_14 2_15      2_16      2_17 2_18 2_19 2_20 2_21 2_22 2_23      2_24
    #1    a2p1u8 0.00000000   0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.03682313 0.07897160 0.19870768 0.83608201 1.0000000 0.4174023    0    0    0    1 0.9914917 0.4329065    0    0    0    0    0    0 0.0000000
    #2    a2qab2 0.00000000   0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0 0.0000000 1.0000000    0    0    0    0    0    0 0.0000000
    #3    a6zl23 0.00000000   0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0    0    1 0.6587305
    #4    a6zlf3 0.00000000   0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000 0.84307423 0.89538282 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0    0    0 0.0000000
    #5    a6zq61 0.06556591   1 0.1294468 0.07020208 0.05969597 0.07020208 0.02732264 0.03284458 0.01107938 0.0268692 0.0000000    0    0    0    0 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0    0    0 0.0000000
    #6    a6ztx1 0.00000000   0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000 0.54465876 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0    0    0 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with your dataset, which I've called `df`, I think this does the trick. It needs you to pass `df` to it and the rest is handled in the code, I'm sure you can put it in a function yourself -

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

dt <- data.table(df)
setnames(dt,'Gene name','Genename')
dtMelted <- data.table(melt(dt, id.vars = 'Genename'))

# correctly ordering
dtMelted[,variableno := match(variable ,colnames(dt))]

# identiftying possible local maximas
setkeyv(dtMelted, c('Genename','variableno'))
dtMelted[,MaxBefore := c(0,diff(value)), by = Genename]
dtMelted[,MaxAfter := -c(diff(value),0), by = Genename]

# adding 80% criteria
dtMelted[,pctcutoffmet := ifelse(value / max(value) > .8, TRUE, FALSE), by = Genename]

# isolating local maximas
dtMeltedLocalMaximas <- dtMelted[
  MaxAfter >= 0 & MaxBefore >= 0
  & !(MaxBefore ==0 & MaxAfter ==0)
  & pctcutoffmet == TRUE
  ]

# merging to nearest local maxima, assuming that key(dtFinalMelted) = key(dtMeltedLocalMAximas) = c('Genename','variableno')
dtFinalMelted <- dtMeltedLocalMaximas[dtMelted, roll = 'nearest']

#  calculating pct of local maxima
dtFinalMelted[,valuepctoflocalmaxima := value.1 / value]

# reformatting to original structure
dtFinal <- dcast(dtFinalMelted, Genename ~ variableno, value.var = 'valuepctoflocalmaxima', fun.aggregate = sum)

# setting column names correctly
setnames(dtFinal,colnames(df))
```

Output (in which I used round(value.1 / value,2) instead of as above) -

```
> dput(dtFinal)
structure(list(`Gene name` = structure(1:6, .Label = c("a2p1u8", 
"a2qab2", "a6zl23", "a6zlf3", "a6zq61", "a6ztx1", "a6zw47", "a6zya9", 
"a7a095", "a7a0l4", "b2g4d8", "b2g4i6", "b2g4p9", "b2g4u5", "b2zbw7", 
"b3lgx6", "b3lh69", "b3lha4", "b3ljq6", "b3llk0", "b3lp17", "b3ltm6", 
"b5vdr5", "b5ve00", "b5ve47", "b5ve66", "b5ve75", "b5vea8", "b5ved3", 
"b5vej5", "b5vfh0", "b5vfm0", "b5vfq6", "b5vg00", "b5vgm8", "b5vgw4", 
"b5vh77", "b5vi95", "b5vif4", "b5vik7", "b5vik8", "b5viu6", "b5vj32", 
"b5vjc2", "b5vji2", "b5vk65", "b5vkc9", "b5vkd1", "b5vkr2", "b5vkr3", 
"b5vl55", "b5vl71", "b5vla9", "b5vlc1", "b5vln1", "b5vlr4", "b5vm13", 
"b5vm96", "b5vmw7", "b5vn73", "b5vnb6", "b5vnc3", "b5vnj1", "b5vnk1", 
"b5vp33", "b5vp56", "b5vpx6", "b5vq26", "b5vq44", "b5vq52", "b5vqk3", 
"b5vrj3", "b5vrz5", "b5vs89", "b5vsy8", "c7gni0", "c7gq32", "c7gqn5", 
"c7gtn6", "c7gu46", "c7gwe7", "c7gxt0", "c8z669", "c8z6f5", "c8z6r4", 
"c8z6v4", "c8zbm1", "c8zcu8", "c8zd16", "c8zhg0", "e7k9a7", "e7k9i7", 
"e7ka19", "e7ka28", "e7kag3", "e7kak7", "e7kau5", "e7kb37", "e7kbg6", 
"e7kbp6", "e7kde5", "e7kdf5", "e7kdl8", "e7kec6", "e7kek6", "e7ker2", 
"e7kez8", "e7kfj1", "e7kg86", "e7kgg6", "e7kgj9", "e7kgm9", "e7kh79", 
"e7khz2", "e7kid1", "e7kid2", "e7kij3", "e7kip9", "e7kiv1", "e7kj59", 
"e7kjc9", "e7kjz8", "e7kkg8", "e7kks4", "e7kkx7", "e7klq2", "e7km62", 
"e7kmw1", "e7kni6", "e7knq6", "e7knx6", "e7kp09", "e7kps9", "e7kql6", 
"e7kqt5", "e7kr71", "e7krc8", "e7krj9", "e7krs0", "e7ks72", "e7ksf4", 
"e7ksg0", "e7ksv0", "e7ku26", "e7kui4", "e7kuz1", "e7kv21", "e7kvp5", 
"e7lr73", "e7lrn1", "e7ls46", "e7ls63", "e7lsa7", "e7lsk8", "e7lsm3", 
"e7lsy6", "e7lte7", "e7ltk1", "e7ltv7", "e7lu34", "e7lun6", "e7lup5", 
"e7lux5", "e7lv27", "e7lw21", "e7lw44", "e7lwa5", "e7lwl6", "e7lwm3", 
"e7lx88", "e7lxj7", "e7lxn8", "e7lxp5", "e7ly02", "e7lyz3", "e7lz85", 
"e7lzh7", "e7lzn6", "e7m129", "e7ney3", "e7nf47", "e7nfe5", "e7nfq5", 
"e7nfz0", "e7ng34", "e7nh47", "e7nh77", "e7nhb2", "e7nhq7", "e7nie7", 
"e7nii6", "e7nir5", "e7nje2", "e7njk4", "e7njv1", "e7nk19", "e7nk28", 
"e7nkm6", "e7nl37", "e7nl74", "e7nlc7", "e7nlm1", "e7nlr2", "e7nlt8", 
"e7nm31", "e7nm99", "e7nmz4", "e7nn89", "e7npc6", "e7q121", "e7q1a1", 
"e7q1e1", "e7q1k7", "e7q1t1", "e7q1x8", "e7q2c3", "e7q2x6", "e7q3f3", 
"e7q3m4", "e7q3x2", "e7q4c4", "e7q4i8", "e7q5g3", "e7q5l9", "e7q5p8", 
"e7q6a9", "e7q6d5", "e7q800", "e7q814", "e7q825", "e7q833", "e7q8i6", 
"e7q8q5", "e7q8r1", "e7q8u9", "e7q8y1", "e7qbg0", "e7qcc5", "e7qcf3", 
"e7qd66", "e7qdy4", "e7qdy8", "e7qe39", "e7qf79", "e7qfn0", "e7qgb5", 
"e7qh38", "e7qh57", "e7qh90", "e7qhj0", "e7qhj7", "e7qhk8", "e7qi53", 
"e7qi89", "e7qii2", "e7qiq0", "e7qiv9", "e7qje4", "e7qjm1", "e7qjn3", 
"e7qjz3", "e7qka0", "e7qkh1", "e7qki3", "e7ql07", "e7ql23", "e7ql56", 
"e7qle4", "e7qlh7", "e7qlm1", "e7qlq3", "e9p8k6", "e9p9c8", "e9p9h6", 
"e9p9y2", "f8ka88", "g1uaw4", "g2w8j6", "g2wax6", "g2wbs0", "g2wbt1", 
"g2wc37", "g2we94", "g2weh9", "g2wej8", "g2wf31", "g2wgt2", "g2whe0", 
"g2wi84", "g2wlm2", "g2wmh7", "g2wmk0", "g2wnc9", "h0gc43", "h0gc45", 
"h0gc46", "h0gc71", "h0gcc4", "h0gce3", "h0gce7", "h0gcg9", "h0gcx2", 
"h0gd06", "h0gd44", "h0gd98", "h0gda5", "h0gda8", "h0gdj5", "h0gdq8", 
"h0gdr5", "h0gdt8", "h0ger5", "h0geu6", "h0gf09", "h0gf24", "h0gf63", 
"h0gfb9", "h0gfx9", "h0gg75", "h0ggk6", "h0ggy4", "h0gh33", "h0gh37", 
"h0ghf6", "h0ghg0", "h0ghh6", "h0ghk6", "h0gig2", "h0gim1", "h0giq8", 
"h0gir4", "h0gj73", "h0gk02", "h0gk39", "h0gk56", "h0gkc0", "h0gkh0", 
"h0gl26", "h0gl41", "h0gle1", "h0glz7", "h0gm98", "h0gmi5", "h0gmp1", 
"h0gmp4", "h0gms2", "h0gmz5", "h0gn89", "h0gp57", "h0gp81", "h0gp99", 
"h0gpm9", "h0gq90", "h0gqv1", "h0gqv6", "h0gr16", "h0gr46", "h0gr62", 
"h0grh5", "h0grj7", "h0grp5", "h0gru2", "h0gry2", "h0grz3", "h0gs82", 
"h0gs88", "h0gsa9", "h0gsk0", "h0gsl8", "h0gsu6", "h0gtf9", "h0gti8", 
"h0gtn2", "h0gts6", "h0gu87", "h0gug5", "h0guj4", "h0gur2", "h0gut3", 
"h0guu5", "h0gux5", "h0gv21", "h0gv78", "h0gvm9", "h0gvn0", "h0gw05", 
"h0gw07", "h0gwi0", "h0gwr8", "h0gx56", "h0gx58", "h0gx70", "h0gx75", 
"h0gxf9", "h0gxg6", "h0gxy4", "h0gxz9", "h0gy93", "h0gys0", "h0gyu8", 
"h0gyz2", "h0gz20", "h0gzc0", "h0gzd5", "h0gzx8", "h0h061", "h0h0j5", 
"h0h0s1", "h0h0t9", "h0h1f1", "h0h1m4", "h0h1r9", "h0h1t7", "h0h216", 
"h0h220", "h0h251", "h0h294", "h0h2j1", "i7ji35", "i7ktc2", "n1nwq1", 
"n1nxi5", "n1ny73", "n1nyf2", "n1nyt5", "n1nyw8", "n1nz14", "n1nzs8", 
"n1p080", "n1p0a4", "n1p0i3", "n1p0w1", "n1p1a9", "n1p1r0", "n1p242", 
"n1p2s1", "n1p2s2", "n1p3w6", "n1p4p6", "n1p4q6", "n1p4r9", "n1p548", 
"n1p5a6", "n1p5i1", "n1p605", "n1p7b3", "n1p858", "n1p8d9", "n1p8f8", 
"n1p8l5", "n1p910", "n1pa29", "n1pa30", "o13429", "o13516", "o14455", 
"o14467", "o43137", "p00358", "p00359", "p00360", "p00431", "p00445", 
"p00498", "p00549", "p00560", "p00635", "p00729", "p00812", "p00815", 
"p00817", "p00830", "p00890", "p00899", "p00924", "p00925", "p00931", 
"p00942", "p00950", "p00958", "p01120", "p01123", "p02309", "p02400", 
"p02406", "p02557", "p02829", "p02992", "p02994", "p03962", "p03965", 
"p04037", "p04046", "p04050", "p04076", "p04147", "p04161", "p04456", 
"p04801", "p04802", "p04806", "p04807", "p05150", "p05317", "p05318", 
"p05319", "p05373", "p05694", "p05737", "p05738", "p05739", "p05740", 
"p05743", "p05744", "p05745", "p05747", "p05749", "p05750", "p05755", 
"p05756", "p05759", "p06101", "p06106", "p06168", "p06169", "p06174", 
"p06208", "p06244", "p06367", "p06634", "p06738", "p07149", "p07170", 
"p07172", "p07244", "p07245", "p07246", "p07256", "p07257", "p07258", 
"p07259", "p07260", "p07262", "p07263.2", "p07264", "p07274", 
"p07275", "p07277", "p07281", "p07283", "p07284", "p07285", "p07560", 
"p07702", "p07703", "p07806.2", "p07884.2", "p07991", "p08465", 
"p08518", "p08524", "p08536", "p08566", "p09064", "p09436", "p09624", 
"p09733", "p09734", "p09880", "p09938", "p0c2h7", "p0c2h8", "p0cs90", 
"p0ct05", "p0cx11", "p0cx24", "p0cx26", "p0cx30", "p0cx32", "p0cx34", 
"p0cx36", "p0cx38", "p0cx40", "p0cx42", "p0cx44", "p0cx48", "p0cx50", 
"p0cx52", "p0cx54", "p0cx56", "p0cx83", "p0cx85", "p10081", "p10127", 
"p10356", "p10591", "p10592", "p10594.2", "p10659", "p10664", 
"p10869", "p10964", "p11076", "p11154", "p11353", "p11412", "p11484", 
"p11745", "p12612", "p12630", "p12709", "p12904", "p12945", "p13188", 
"p13298", "p13663", "p14065", "p14120", "p14126", "p14127", "p14306", 
"p14540", "p14743", "p14832", "p14843", "p14904", "p15019", "p15108", 
"p15180", "p15202", "p15303", "p15424", "p15454", "p15496", "p15624", 
"p15625", "p15646", "p15703", "p15705", "p15790", "p15873", "p15992", 
"p16120", "p16140", "p16370", "p16387", "p16467", "p16474", "p16550", 
"p16603", "p16649", "p16861", "p17076", "p17255", "p17423", "p17505", 
"p17555", "p17649", "p17709", "p17967", "p18544", "p18562", "p18962", 
"p19097", "p19262", "p19414", "p19454", "p19812", "p19881", "p19882", 
"p20081", "p20133", "p20433", "p20434", "p20436", "p20459", "p20967", 
"p21242", "p21243", "p21524", "p21801", "p21826", "p22023", "p22108", 
"p22138", "p22141", "p22146", "p22202", "p22203", "p22217", "p22336", 
"p22515", "p22696", "p22803", "p23180", "p23248", "p23254", "p23301", 
"p23638", "p23639", "p23724", "p23776", "p24000", "p24280", "p24521", 
"p24783", "p24859", "p25036", "p25043", "p25293", "p25328", "p25332", 
"p25359", "p25373", "p25375", "p25443", "p25451", "p25491", "p25567", 
"p25572", "p25631", "p25632", "p25638", "p25654", "p25694", "p25719", 
"p26321", "p26637", "p26755", "p26783", "p26784", "p26785", "p26786", 
"p27466", "p27472", "p27476", "p27614", "p27616", "p27929", "p28000", 
"p28241", "p28272", "p28273", "p28274", "p28319", "p28495", "p28707", 
"p28777", "p28834", "p29311", "p29453", "p29509", "p29547", "p29952", 
"p30402", "p30656", "p30657", "p30952", "p31115", "p31116", "p31209", 
"p31373", "p31383", "p31412", "p31539", "p31688", "p32178", "p32179", 
"p32288", "p32324", "p32327", "p32337", "p32347", "p32356", "p32377", 
"p32379", "p32381", "p32445", "p32452", "p32459", "p32460", "p32461", 
"p32469", "p32471", "p32474", "p32481", "p32485", "p32486", "p32495", 
"p32497", "p32527", "p32529", "p32558", "p32565", "p32582", "p32589", 
"p32590", "p32598", "p32604", "p32614", "p32626", "p32628", "p32643", 
"p32656", "p32767", "p32771", "p32774", "p32775", "p32835", "p32836", 
"p32860", "p32895", "p32905", "p32939", "p33201", "p33204", "p33298", 
"p33307", "p33312", "p33315", "p33317", "p33327", "p33330", "p33399", 
"p33401", "p33412", "p33416", "p33442", "p33734", "p34162", "p34167", 
"p34223", "p34227", "p34760", "p35176", "p35184", "p35189", "p35195", 
"p35691", "p35719", "p35844", "p36008", "p36010", "p36015", "p36017", 
"p36018", "p36037", "p36047", "p36060", "p36069", "p36104", "p36136", 
"p36156", "p36159", "p36421", "p37012", "p37254", "p37291", "p37292", 
"p37302", "p37303", "p37898", "p38009", "p38011", "p38013", "p38061", 
"p38066", "p38067", "p38071", "p38075", "p38081", "p38088.2", 
"p38109", "p38113", "p38115", "p38145", "p38197", "p38199", "p38203", 
"p38205", "p38237", "p38254", "p38260", "p38328", "p38331", "p38431", 
"p38439", "p38523", "p38555", "p38616", "p38620", "p38623", "p38625", 
"p38627", "p38628", "p38687", "p38688", "p38693", "p38697", "p38698", 
"p38701", "p38707", "p38710", "p38711", "p38715", "p38716", "p38754", 
"p38764", "p38765", "p38774", "p38777", "p38787", "p38788", "p38791", 
"p38792", "p38797", "p38804", "p38820", "p38840", "p38841", "p38858", 
"p38861", "p38879", "p38882", "p38888", "p38891", "p38902", "p38930", 
"p38972", "p38986", "p38999", "p39076", "p39079", "p39522", "p39676", 
"p39683", "p39692", "p39708", "p39714", "p39721", "p39929", "p39939", 
"p39954", "p39958", "p39976", "p39979", "p39988", "p39990", "p40011", 
"p40016", "p40029", "p40032", "p40037", "p40043", "p40047", "p40054", 
"p40069", "p40070", "p40075", "p40087", "p40089", "p40106", "p40185", 
"p40302", "p40354", "p40363", "p40414", "p40422", "p40454", "p40459", 
"p40495", "p40498", "p40506", "p40509", "p40510", "p40531", "p40545", 
"p40553", "p40581", "p40586", "p40825.2", "p41057", "p41058", 
"p41277", "p41338", "p41752", "p41805", "p41811", "p41816", "p41835", 
"p41895", "p41896", "p41920", "p41921", "p41939", "p41940", "p42935", 
"p42936", "p42941", "p42943", "p43561", "p43567", "p43583", "p43590", 
"p43593", "p43616", "p43621", "p46151", "p46654", "p46655", "p46669", 
"p46672", "p46680", "p46948", "p46959", "p46969", "p46990", "p47008", 
"p47079", "p47089", "p47095", "p47096", "p47103", "p47117", "p47119", 
"p47120", "p47164", "p47173", "p47176", "p47771", "p48164", "p48362", 
"p48363", "p48445", "p48526", "p48567", "p48589", "p49017", "p49089", 
"p49090", "p49166", "p49167", "p49367", "p49435", "p49723", "p49775", 
"p49954", "p49957", "p50086", "p50094", "p50095", "p50101", "p50264", 
"p50861", "p50946", "p51401", "p51601", "p51996", "p52488", "p52489", 
"p52910", "p52918", "p53072", "p53090", "p53095", "p53110", "p53111", 
"p53128", "p53144", "p53164", "p53177", "p53183", "p53184", "p53196", 
"p53221", "p53228", "p53235", "p53255", "p53256", "p53265", "p53270", 
"p53303", "p53315", "p53319", "p53334", "p53342", "p53598", "p53615", 
"p53633", "p53720", "p53727", "p53731", "p53759", "p53834", "p53839", 
"p53848", "p53909", "p53912", "p53920", "p53980", "p53981", "p54113", 
"p54114", "p54115", "p54838", "p54839", "p54885", "p60010", "p80210", 
"p83774", "p87262", "p89886", "q00055", "q00618", "q00711", "q00764", 
"q00955", "q01855", "q02326", "q02455", "q02642", "q02648", "q02725", 
"q02821", "q02892", "q02933", "q03034", "q03048", "q03102", "q03161", 
"q03262", "q03280", "q03532", "q03558", "q03629", "q03677", "q03690", 
"q03771", "q03774", "q03940", "q04066", "q04119", "q04120", "q04175", 
"q04178", "q04212", "q04225", "q04336", "q04401", "q04409", "q04430", 
"q04432", "q04491", "q04533", "q04636", "q04660", "q04728", "q04792", 
"q04894", "q04947", "q04951", "q05016", "q05022", "q05506", "q05515", 
"q05533", "q05583", "q05636", "q05778", "q05788", "q05905", "q05911", 
"q05933", "q05946", "q05979", "q06053", "q06103", "q06137", "q06146", 
"q06151", "q06252", "q06338", "q06385", "q06406", "q06408", "q06440", 
"q06494", "q06523", "q06608", "q06624", "q06625", "q06672", "q06706", 
"q07381", "q07505", "q07527", "q07532", "q07551", "q07589", "q07648", 
"q07938", "q08162", "q08220", "q08245", "q08421", "q08634", "q08647", 
"q08686", "q08745", "q08920", "q08924", "q08952", "q08971", "q08977", 
"q08985", "q12008", "q12009", "q12040", "q12074", "q12091", "q12109", 
"q12118", "q12122", "q12123", "q12159", "q12168", "q12189", "q12211", 
"q12242", "q12277", "q12283", "q12306", "q12314", "q12329", "q12335", 
"q12341", "q12363", "q12377", "q12400", "q12408", "q12414", "q12434", 
"q12447", "q12449", "q12455", "q12458", "q12460", "q12464", "q12496", 
"q12522", "q12525", "q12680", "q3e754", "q3e792", "q3e7x9", "q3e7y3", 
"q6fjy0_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fl72_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fmr2_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fns7_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fph8_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fpi1_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fpn8_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fpp1_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fr31_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6frs2_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fst2_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6ftb3_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6ftj1_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6ftk5_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fvr0_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fwr8_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6fx34_cangasimilartouniprot", "q6fxu9_cangasimilartouniprot", 
"q6q560", "q74z16", "q74z48", "q74zf6", "q74zm9", "q750e3", "q750u5", 
"q750z7", "q751d8", "q752q7", "q752w6", "q753p8", "q753t3", "q753w1", 
"q753y2", "q754c8", "q754d6", "q754f6", "q755g1", "q755g8", "q755q5", 
"q756e2", "q756e7", "q756f7", "q756k2", "q756u4", "q756y3", "q757i1", 
"q757l4", "q757n1", "q757y2", "q758l1", "q758t1", "q759a3", "q759a4", 
"q759a9", "q759i7", "q759v7", "q75aa5", "q75bc3", "q75bq6", "q75bv8", 
"q75c57", "q75cf8", "q75cn6", "q75df8", "q75dp6", "q75dq0", "q75ds7", 
"q75du3", "q75dw1", "q75en0", "q75ew2", "q75f01", "q87026", "q8j1f8", 
"q8j2m3", "q8mx29", "q96vh4", "q99210", "q99258", "q99312", "q9p4c2", 
"s4vpl7", "s5s176", "t2a536", "v5rd14"), class = "factor"), `2_1` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0), `2_2` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2_3` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.13, 0), `2_4` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0), `2_5` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.06, 0), `2_6` = c(0.04, 0, 0, 1, 0.07, 1), `2_7` = c(0.08, 
0, 0, 0.84, 0.03, 0.54), `2_8` = c(0.2, 0, 0, 1, 0.03, 0), `2_9` = c(0.84, 
0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0), `2_10` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0), `2_11` = c(0.42, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_12` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_13` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `2_14` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_15` = c(1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `2_16` = c(0.99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_17` = c(0.43, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `2_18` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_19` = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `2_20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_21` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), `2_22` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_23` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0), `2_24` = c(0, 0, 0.66, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Gene name", 
"2_1", "2_2", "2_3", "2_4", "2_5", "2_6", "2_7", "2_8", "2_9", 
"2_10", "2_11", "2_12", "2_13", "2_14", "2_15", "2_16", "2_17", 
"2_18", "2_19", "2_20", "2_21", "2_22", "2_23", "2_24"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Only works when the local maxima are separated by zero values (which was specified in the post):

```
localmaxima <- function(Row) {
  row.max <- max(Row)
  # Zeros identify the boundaries 
  stops = unique( c(1, which(Row == 0), L) )
  for ( i in seq(length(stops) - 1) ) {
    win = stops[i]:stops[i+1]
    intermediate.max = max(Row[win])
    if ( intermediate.max >= .2 * row.max ) {
      Row[win] <- Row[win] / intermediate.max
    } else {
      Row[win] <- 0
    }   
  }   
  return(Row)
}   

# The input:
Mat
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
Greg      0   30   50   10    0   30   60
Mike     20   50   30    0    0    2    0
Susane   30    0   10    0  100   30    0
Marcel    0   40   30   10    0    2    0

# The output:
t(apply(Mat, 1, localmaxima))
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
Greg    0.0  0.6 1.00 0.20    0  0.5    1
Mike    0.4  1.0 0.60 0.00    0  0.0    0
Susane  1.0  0.0 0.00 0.00    1  0.3    0
Marcel  0.0  1.0 0.75 0.25    0  0.0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different solution, I'd started so I thought i'd finish.
The hardest part was creating the local maximums which I did with sublists breaking at zero. Not the best way I don't think in hindsight as there are some annoying corner cases to work around.

(NB - You can add add the 20% criteria to each sublist by using a && operator on each if - from your examples I can't exactly see what behaviour you want in those instances.)

After that it's fairly straightforward to replicate the maximum value for the length of the list. When you put it back together you have a list of dividers rather than a list of indexes. (With a catch when the value is zero so you divide by 1). Apply this to every row of the starting matrix to create a divider matrix. The final step is an element wise multiplication of the inverse of these with the original matrix.

My local_list function with all the if functions is quite ugly, but the local_max and then bdv functions are a bit tidier.

```
local_list <- function(x) {
    #Initialise Variables
    L = list()
    i = 0
    k = 1
    previous_zero = FALSE

        for (j in 1:length(x)){
            if (x[j] == 0) {
                if (previous_zero == TRUE){
                    L[k] <- list(x[j])
                    k <- k+1
                    i<-j+1
                }
                else {
                    if (j==1){
                        L[k] <- list(x[j])
                        i <- j+1
                        k <- k+1
                    }
                    else {
                    L[k] <- list(x[i:(j-1)])
                    L[k+1] <- list(x[j]);
                    k <- k+2
                    i <- j+1
                    }
                }
            previous_zero <- TRUE
            }
            else {
                previous_zero = FALSE
            }


            if (j==length(x) && x[j] != 0) {
            L[k] <- list(x[i:length(x)])
            }
        }
return(L)
} 


localmax <- function(y) {
  if (max(unlist(y)) == 0){
    rep(1,length(y))
  }
  else {rep(max(unlist(y)),length(unlist(y)))}
  }

bdv <- function(x){                            #Build Divider Vector
    return((unlist(sapply(local_list(x), localmax))))
}
```

Having prepared the function calls create the sample matrix.

```
Greg <- c(0, 30, 50, 10, 0, 30, 60)
Mike <- c(20, 50, 30, 0, 0, 2, 0)
Susane <- c(30, 0, 10, 0, 100, 30, 0)
Marcel <- c(0, 40, 30, 10, 0, 2, 0)

Mat <- rbind(Greg,Mike,Susane,Marcel)
```

The output then becomes an element wise multiplication

```
dm <- t(1/(apply(Mat,1,bdv)))
output <- Mat * dm
```